# My file meet Brackets live preview problematic situation, no problematic situation concerning “Getting Started” file, although

Tags: adobe-brackets

I can use live preview when I selected **“Getting Started” file**,
but I cannot use live preview when I selected **the file that I created**.
This file is in same tree as “Getting Started”.
I already insert “"livedev.multibrowser" true” into json file which is in the place,
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Brackets.
What’s the difference?
Should I set something for my file?
FYI, when I restart Brackets, json file becomes “false” again.
Is this related?

FYI-2,I checked address.(I don’t update this to any public server, still.)
my file
http://127.0.0.1:56616/index.html
Getting Started
http://127.0.0.1:56598/index.html

Comment: You should some code for us to be able to help you

Comment: Code of this file?
Well, I don’t hesitate to show code, but is it meaningful?
There are 850 lines(HTML) and 1200 lines (css). Very long codes.
Is it OK to summarize?

P.S.
I tried copy and paste my coded HTML file(without css) to “Getting started2”(I just changed folder name from “Getting started” and files are completely same), but Live preview doesn’t work.
However I copy and paste “Getting started” code to that file back again, then Live preview work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently done an update to brackets? If so then they say on their github issues log that it is best to remove the cached files and the appdata files because it has a hard dependency and that should reset the program. This link may help[enter link description here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/11670)

Comment: >Have you recently done an update to brackets?

Yea-h. I vaguely remember. I think I did or I think didn’t.
I scrutinize your suggestion, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to their github account I'd you do a version update the software can bug out and their main fix is deleting the app data but you can leave the preferences. It requires a clean install of brackets for it to function with 1.3 1.4 1.5

Comment: @user3449751 My apologies for late reply but you're welcome. I personally have since stopped using the software but glad some people are still using it and getting help from this suggestion

Comment: You don't need to apologize and don't care. hehe (^^♪